# How to print two numbers from the same list in Python 2.7

Tags: python, short

So i was assigned to make a short programm for skill development on lists.
Here's the code:

```
x=[21,23,25,27]
y=[5,6,7,8]
z=x+y
print (z)
z[0]=45
print (z)
a=[x+y]
print a
print (a[1][2])
```

What we are asked to do is to guess what will the code print.But the last line doesnt work and i always get errors.That line was given straight from the given exercise.The only way to show the [1] and [2] element is to do it in a for i in range command am i correct?I have tried other syntaxes that dont work and i believe that this is the only way.

Comment: Long time ago, but 'for a, b in izip(x, y):', might be worth a look here

Answer (score 1):

`a=[x+y]`, here `+` will create a new list and add it inside another list so to create 2D list with two inner list, use `,` which act as separator where as `+` act as a concatenation operation so use `,` as

```
a=[x,y]
```

---

To print elements with same index using single indexing with new list, we can create a 2D list with keeping same index values together as

```
x=[21,23,25,27]
y=[5,6,7,8]
z=x+y
print (z)
z[0]=45
print (z)
a = [[i,j] for i,j in zip(x,y)]
# i is element in x and j is element in y
# [i,j] a new list with elements i and j
print(a)
#a=[x,y]
print (a[0]) # [21,5]
```

Comment: I want to show the first and second element of a list.And the last line is incorrect.How can i print those elements?Just with print a[1] print a[2]?

Comment: what you can do is combine both list to create 2d array with same elements of index together

Answer (score 0):

You could use a  for statement like you said. But there's also another way. You could try this:

```
print(a[:3])
```

The above code will basically print the elements in a from start till 2, i.e., before 3.

Answer (score 0):

The error is down to the index `a[1]`.

example:

```
x=[21,23,25,27]
y=[5,6,7,8]
z=x+y
print (z)
z[0]=45
print (z)
# a = list of lists, where x+y is the first and only list [[x+y],...]
a=[x+y]
print(a)
# print [x+y]
print (a[0])
# a[1][2] here 1 was out of bounds
# a[0][2] the third member of list [0], i.e. [x+y]
print (a[0][2])
# list of lists, with two memmbers [x, y]
a = [z,y]
print(a)
# first member of x
print(a[0][0])
# print first member of y
print(a[1][0])
```

output:

```
# print (z)
[21, 23, 25, 27, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# print(z)
[45, 23, 25, 27, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# print(a)
[[21, 23, 25, 27, 5, 6, 7, 8]]
# print(a[0])
[21, 23, 25, 27, 5, 6, 7, 8]
# print(a[0][2])
25
# print([z,y])
[[45, 23, 25, 27, 5, 6, 7, 8], [5, 6, 7, 8]]
# print a[0][0]
45
# print a[1][0]
5
```

Answer (score 0):

there is either a mistake in the question you've been given or in your writing it in here, as a doesn't have an index 1.

a has one element in it, which is a list. that list is the same as z

```
z = x+y
```

makes a new list with all x and y elements

```
a = [x+y]
```

a is the same as [z] the z list inside a list

inside a is only a[0] which is the list of x+y

you could have a[0][2] which is 25

but there is no a[1]